# How can I check if a queue exists on ActivemQ "Classic"?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I have this method that throws me an exception when the data queue doesn't exists, but is not. Do you have other way to solve this?

```java
public void checkDataQueue(String dataQueue) throws JMSException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    connection = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Queue queue = session.createQueue(dataQueue);
    QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ 5.x creates Queues on demand by default so you may have changed the default configuration to disallow this in which case the error should be expected to happen if you are hitting a non-existent queue and you should check for and handle that.  If you need to be sure then the broker provides a [JMX](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx) interface to query for information on broker statistics etc.  There are also other ways of monitoring such as using Rest style calls over the Jolokia management interface.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:

```java
public boolean existDataQueue(String dataQueue) throws JMSException {
    boolean response = false;
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory =
        new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
    ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection)activeMQConnectionFactory.createConnection();

    connection.start();

    DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();

    Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();

    for (ActiveMQQueue activeMQQueue : queues) {
        try {
            if(activeMQQueue.getQueueName().equalsIgnoreCase(dataQueue)) {
                response = true;
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    connection.close();
    return response;
}
```

Comment: There are several reasons to not rely on this mechanism first and foremost being that it fails if any disables advisory support on the broker.  Also you need to check many times before assuming that the queue doesn't exist here as the population of the source is not immediate.